# Why is my Angular app blank on Github Pages?

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am trying to host my Angular app on Github Pages at jhuynh13.github.io but the page is blank. I look into the developer tools and I see this error:

Failed to load resource: /runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js:1
the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I searched for this file and I found it in the repo for jhuynh13.github.io here:

[image]

I'm not sure what I can do with this file though to debug. What might be going on here?

Comment: `runtime-es2015` != `runtime-es5`. There's no ES2015 version of that file in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

your base href looks like

```
<base href="<jhuynh13.github.io>">
```

But it should look like, change into this

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: I made the adjustment in the index html file but the same error remains.

Comment: Try to resolved by setting type="text/javascript" instead of type="module". in index.html

Comment: It turns out that I had to ng build and update the dist folder because ng serve doesnt update it automatically. It works now. Thanks for the input

Comment: Hello @UsmanAli
Thank you so much
It has worked

Answer (score 1):

My dist folder was outdated. I was able to fix it by using ng build --watch in the angular cli. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I change the base url in the index.html file from `<base href='/'>` to

```
<base href='/name-of-repo/'
```

the ending `/` is important don't forget this one.